# Bash: Extract part of archive to another directory

Tags: bash, archive, tar

This is my file:

```
archive.tar.gz:
archive/
archive/a/
archive/a/b/c/file1
archive/a/b/c/file2
archive/a/b/c/file3
```

And I want to extract this to:
`a/c`

I placed `archive.tag.gz` in folder `a`
I went to folder `a`

I launched:
`tar -zxvf archive.tar.gz a/b/c -C a/c`

But instead of placing content of folder `c` to `a/c` it is placing to `a/b/c`. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would do :

`tar -xvzf archive.tar.gz --strip-components=2 -C a/c a/b/c`

`--strip-components=n` will remove the `n` first path component of the files extracted